# Correct syntax to use new for char* array

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc

I have the following

```
typedef struct
{
    int        titleCount; 
    char**     titles;
} myStruct;
```

And then

```
...
struct1->titleCount = 2;
struct1->titles = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (str->titleCount + 1));
...
```

What would be the correct syntax for using `new` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: The most accepted way is `std::vector<std::string> titles;` and then you're all good to go.

Comment: Can't help. Pre-existing code :(

Comment: Why is the existing code allocating memory for 3 `char *` when you have 2 titles? Are you filling the last spot with NULL and using that as a delimiter?

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, I guess that would be the reason

Comment: @ontherocks, Then what's `titleCount`'s purpose? I mean I would prefer the variable over the delimiter, but having both is a bit...pointless.

Comment: If you are porting from C to C++ why are you doing half measures. Might as well leave the `malloc` in until you can make a good job of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the example, titles points to an array of pointers to char or most probably actually strings. So I would expect something like:

```
titles = new char*[str->titleCount]; // or maybe keep the +1
```

followed by a loop to allocate the individual strings and put pointers to them into the array pointed-to by titles.

Comment: This works. However I am able to assign 2 strings to `titles` even without specifying the size in `[]`. Why so?

Comment: I think if you do new char*[] you get one char* allocated. Being able to store 2 string pointers there is pure luck - the second one has overwritten memory that it should not have, which will lead to undefined behaviour at best, your program crashing immediately at worst.

Comment: Yes I guess, and that's the reason even `new char*` (without the braces) works.

Comment: Absolutely - though I am unsure if new char*[] is part of the standard (probably yes), new char* **absolutely** is as this is the way you allocate a single instance of anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you are porting from C to C++, the better solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::string> myTitles;
```

The entire struct is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code of allocating memory is invalid because you may not write

```
struct1->titleCount
```

unless somewhere you wrote

```
struct struct1 *struct1 = malloc( sizeof( struct struct1 ) );
```

However from the code you presented it seems that you need to allocate

```
str->titleCount + 1
```

elements of type `char *`

So the corresponding code will look as

```
str->titleCount = 2;
str->titles = new char * [str->titleCount + 1];
```

Next time please show a code snippet that could be compiled. From you code it is not clear what is struct1 and str. You only confuse others.